# Java build time constant configuration

Tags: java, ant, annotations, constants, final

I have a project I would like to build using multiple configurations. 
I have a constant that needs to be different between builds but I do not know how to change it based on my config.

For example I would like to be able to do the following based off a value in a config file.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://example.com/")
public class CustomerWebService {
```

and

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://demo.example.com/")
public class CustomerWebService {
```

We use ant for building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise attempting to emulate Maven resource filtering and profile properties

## Source filtering

### src/templates/MyFile.java

```
..
@WebService(targetNamespace = "@WS_NAMESPACE@")
public class CustomerWebService {
..
```

### build.xml

```
<target name="filter-sources">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/src">
       <fileset dir="src/templates" includes="**/*.java"/>
       <filterset>
          <filter token="WS_NAMESPACE" value="${ws.namespace}"/>
       </filterset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="filter-sources">
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}/classes">
        <src path="src/java"/>
        <src path="${build.dir}/src"/>
        <classpath>
        ..
        ..
    </javac>
</target>
```

Notes:

- The ANT copy task is capable of performing template substitutions.

## Build profiles

### Property files

Each configuration has a different property file

```
src/properties/dev.properties
src/properties/qa.properties
src/properties/prod.properties
..
```

### build.xml

```
<property name="profile" value="dev"/>
<property file="src/properties/${profile}.properties"/>
```

### Choosing an alternative build profile

```
ant -Dprofile=qa ..
```

Comment: Though it works, but my recommendation is to avoid such kind of 'environment-specific compilation' in your app.  You will finally come to a situation of building multiple times for different environment, and also, the artifact you deploy to production is not the same one as you tested.

Comment: @AdrianShum Yes you are quite correct. A very common build anti-pattern is to build a special file for each deployment. However, sometimes I need to build customer specific artifacts (different license keys, icons, etc) which does justify this effort. In conclusion, the main point of this posting was to demonstrate how Maven features like source filtering and build profiles can be emulated in ANT.