# Parsing xml using ant

Tags: xml, ant

I have an xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>

    <environment env="dev">
        <BASE_URI>dev BASE_URI</BASE_URI>
        <PROXY_HOST>dev PROXY_HOST</PROXY_HOST>
        <PROXY_PORT>dev PROXY_PORT</PROXY_PORT>
    </environment>

    <environment env="dev2">
        <BASE_URI>test3 BASE_URI</BASE_URI>
        <PROXY_HOST>test3 PROXY_HOST</PROXY_HOST>
        <PROXY_PORT>test3 PROXY_PORT</PROXY_PORT>
    </environment>

</Root>
```

From ant, i will take the env as the input and i need to read all the properties of it and write to a file.

Comment: See the following answer for perhaps a simpler way to setup a profile based build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790609/java-build-time-constant-configuration/12790995#12790995

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you want. However, take a look at the [`<xmlproperty>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) task. This reads an XML file and turns it into a list of Ant properties (usually `.` formatted). Then, you can use the [`<echoproperties>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) task to print out those properties into a Java formatted properties file.

Is this what you're looking for?

If I had a bit clearer description, I could give you a coding example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you want. Do you need generate this xml based on env. variables? If so:

- create script(let's say python or shell) which reads env. variable and generate xml file
- add [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) target to your ant script, which runs script created in a prev. step