# Replacing property dynamically based on environments in Ant scripts

Tags: ant

I want to develop ant script which replaces application properties with environment specific properties. My requirement is that I will have all environment properties in single `env.properties` file. During building the application I need to replace with whatever in `env.properties` file. Ant replace works well when I have property files for each environment.

Sample : env.properties

```
dev.AddNETWORK_USER=devUser
dev.ADDPASS=devPass
sit.AddNETWORK_USER=situser
sit.ADDPASS=sitPass
```

This needs be replaced in `mule.properties` as
for DEV environment:

```
dev.AddNETWORK_USER=devUser
dev.ADDPASS=devPass
```

for SIT environment:

```
AddNETWORK_USER=sitUser
ADDPASS=sitPass
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java build time constant configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790609/java-build-time-constant-configuration)

Comment: i already checked that post. This works well for me as well. But if i need to have a single property file for all the environments?

Comment: Why make the solution more complicated? Problem is ANT doesn't support nested property names, for example: ${${ENV}.AddNETWORK_USER}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property ant task on your env.properties file. This allows to access key=value pair based on your need. You can redirect your environment specific properties to file you want or write to one specific file.

```
 <property file="${base.dir}/env.properties"/>
    <for list="dev,sit" param="value">
         <sequential>
              <echo message="@{value}.AddNETWORK_USER=${@{value}.AddNETWORK_USER}" append="true" file="${base.dir}/@{value}Any-File.prop"/>
               <echo message="${line.separator}" append="true" file="${para.home}/@{value}Any-File.prop"/>
               <echo message="@{value}.ADDPASS=${@{value}.ADDPASS}" append="true" file="${para.home}/@{value}Any-File.prop"/>

           </sequential>
     </for>
```